# pass object to mustache template

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I'm working on a project using express with mustache templates, I'm trying to pass object to the template using res.locals but it's not working,

this is the code

```
exports.menu = function(req,res){
    res.locals.title = "Menu";
    res.locals.class_type ="main_nav";
    MenuDB.GetAvailableLunch()
        .then((list) => {
            res.locals.lunch = list;
            console.log('Promise Resolved');
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            console.log('Promise rejected', err);
        })
    res.render('menu');
}
```

I want the list that comes from the function to be the lunch object which I have on the mustache page, any ideas how to do this?
I know that I can just do it like this

```
.then((list) => {
            res.render('menu', {
                'lunch': list
            });
```

but I'm trying to do it this way because I will have another function to return another lists from the database, hope this is clear enough.

Comment: but later I will have another function that returns another list that would be used in the template as well, this is why I'm trying to save it as a variable and have res.render() at the end

Comment: Is the secondary query dependent on the first at all?

Comment: no but it will be inside the same template, can I use .render twice in the same function?

Comment: No, you can only send one response. That means `res.render()` / `res.send()` / etc can only be called once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a promise-chain or array of independent promises and only call `res.render()` once everything is resolved.

For example...

```js
exports.menu = async (req, res) => {
  const [lunch, another] = await Promise.all([
    MenuDB.GetAvailableLunch(),
    anotherFunction(),
  ]);

  res.render("menu", {
    title: "Menu",
    class_type: "main_nav",
    lunch,
    another
  });
};
```